# How to make it so that when a wallet is selected, it is added to the array if it is not there, and if it is, it is removed from the array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is what useCallback looks like, it is constantly overwritten and displays only one selected wallet

```
const [ selectedWallet, setSelectedWallet] = useState<SyncedWalletData | undefined>(undefined);
const onSelectWallet = useCallback((wallet: SyncedWalletData) => setSelectedWallet(wallet), []);
```

Replace useState with this

```
const [ selectedWallet, setSelectedWallet] = useState<SyncedWalletData[]>([]);
```

And the question remains, how to rewrite onSelectWallet so that (all) selected wallets are displayed, i.e. if the wallet is in the array, then you do not need to add it, if it is not in the array, then add it

it is not possible to rewrite onSelectWallet so that everything works as it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your `onSelectWallet` function to:

```
const onSelectWallet = useCallback((wallet: SyncedWalletData) => {
  if (selectedWallet.includes(wallet)) {
    setSelectedWallet(selectedWallet.filter(w => w !== wallet))
  } else {
    setSelectedWallet([...selectedWallet, wallet])
  }
}), []);
```